# WSO2 Access token revoking automatically without explicit request

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 version 5.5.0. We have configured the API manager, publisher, store and Identity server. For unauthenticated user, we are using client_credentials grant along with device scope. So every browser session will have its own access_token and 60 min token expiry time.
With unauthenticated user, we are able to load the application. While accessing the other part application(not logged in flow), API's start responding back with unauthorized(401) error. It fails random time and for random API's. It is not failing specific API call or at specific time, it completely random.

Token gets revoked automatically without getting any call from front-end application.
Please help us to understand what could be wrong with our WSO2 configuration.
What would be the steps to fix this issue?

Other details -
What type of technical details will be required to help you understand the issue?
This is how our set up looks like

API Manager is configured to publish all the API's
Our front-end application is in angular 7
For Anonymous user, we are using client_credential grant with device scope
We are receiving access_token and expiry time from identity server and using it as bearer token along with every API call.
We are able access API's only when we pass request header: Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
We are noticing a 401 error while accessing the API's as our token state got updated to Revoked in the database on its own(before expiry time).
7.As per the link below we checked our configuration for PoolSize and we are using the recommended value of 0.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Token+Persistence

Comment: API Manager response     ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security"><ams:code>900901</ams:code><ams:message>Invalid Credentials</ams:message><ams:description>Access failure for API: /test-api/1.0, version: 1.0 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have given the correct access token</ams:description></ams:fault>

Answer (score 0):

If you generate access tokens from the store portal, it revokes the previous token which has been generated with client_credentials grant type. So if someone does that from UI, you can expect this behavior.

Comment: The scope is device based, our scenario is user A goes and access the UI and issued a token. User B does the same. After a while (well within the expiry time) it is observed the token for both users are revoked.

Comment: Ideally, your app should call the token API and get a token. You shouldn't get a token from UI and hardcode in your app. And the API call gives a 401, the app should request a new token.

Comment: So, Token isnt hard coded on UI. An API call is made to get the token.        
Token generation is using following specs - Basic xxxxxxx-xxxxx
grant_type: client_credentials
scope: device_Unique_Id                                                                                                              Response -                                                                                                                      {"access_token":"access_token_id","scope":"am_application_scope device_Unique_Id","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}

Comment: Also, any idea what logs we can enable to get details on revoke API calls ?